# how to fetch contact image and phone Number in my app using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts, cncontact

I am getting the contact name from my phone.
Check my code:

```
- (void) fetchContacts
{
    CNAuthorizationStatus status = [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts];
    if (status == CNAuthorizationStatusDenied || status == CNAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"This app previously was refused permissions to contacts; Please go to settings and grant permission to this app so it can use contacts" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:TRUE completion:nil];
        return;
    }

    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        // make sure the user granted us access

        if (!granted) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // user didn't grant access;
                // so, again, tell user here why app needs permissions in order  to do it's job;
                // this is dispatched to the main queue because this request could be running on background thread
            });
            return;
        }

        // build array of contacts

        NSMutableArray *contacts = [NSMutableArray array];

        NSError *fetchError;
        CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:@[CNContactIdentifierKey, [CNContactFormatter descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle:CNContactFormatterStyleFullName]]];

        BOOL success = [store enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError usingBlock:^(CNContact *contact, BOOL *stop) {
            [contacts addObject:contact];
        }];



        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"error = %@", fetchError);
        }



        // you can now do something with the list of contacts, for example, to show the names

        CNContactFormatter *formatter = [[CNContactFormatter alloc] init];

        for (CNContact *contact in contacts) {
            if (!_contacts) {
                _contacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            }

            NSString *string = [formatter stringFromContact:contact];
            NSLog(@"contact = %@", string);
            [_contacts addObject:string];
        }
        [_contactatableview reloadData];

    }];
}
```

for this code, I am getting the response

```
2015-12-28 15:18:13.867 finalprototype[2138:66648] contact = John Appleseed
2015-12-28 15:18:13.868 finalprototype[2138:66648] contact = Kate Bell
2015-12-28 15:18:13.868 finalprototype[2138:66648] contact = Anna Haro
2015-12-28 15:18:13.868 finalprototype[2138:66648] contact = Daniel Higgins Jr.
2015-12-28 15:18:13.868 finalprototype[2138:66648] contact = David Taylor
2015-12-28 15:18:13.868 finalprototype[2138:66648] contact = Hank M. Zakroff
```

my requirement is I need to display the image and phone number of a particular contact in my app contacts page.

So is this possible in iOS 9?

give me suggestions

Thank you.

Comment: I have updated the answer according to your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Fetching the image of the contact is easy. I think that you want to show the image of the contact along with the name in the table view. If so, then store each contact's data in your data source array as dictionaries.

```
    for (CNContact *contact in contacts) {
        if (!_contacts) {
            _contacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }

        NSArray<CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber*>*> *phoneNumbers = contact.phoneNumbers;
        CNPhoneNumber *phone = [phoneNumbers[0] value];

        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        NSString *nameString = contact.givenName;
        [dictionary setValue:nameString forKey:@"name"];

        NSString *phoneString = phone.stringValue;
        [dictionary setValue:phoneString forKey:@"phone"];

        if (contact.imageDataAvailable) {
            [dictionary setValue:self.contactToAdd.imageData forKey:@"image"];
        }
        NSLog(@"contact = %@", contact);
        [_contacts addObject:dictionary];
    }
```

And in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method use the dictionary accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
+ (UIImage *)getImageForContactIdentifier:(NSString *)contactIdentifer
{
     NSError *error;
     NSArray *keysToFetch = @[CNContactImageDataAvailableKey, CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey];

     CNContact *contact = [[NWContactManager sharedManger].contactStore unifiedContactWithIdentifier:contactIdentifer keysToFetch:keysToFetch error:&error];

     UIImage *image;
     if (contact.imageDataAvailable) {
          image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.thumbnailImageData];
     }
        return image;
    }

//For iOS8 or below, Use Following code

+ (UIImage *)getImageForContactIdentifier:(NSNumber *)contactIdentifer
{
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABRecordID recId = (ABRecordID)[contactIdentifer intValue];
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
    ABRecordRef contactPerson = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, recId);

    UIImage *image;
    CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(contactPerson);
    if (imageData) {
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:(__bridge NSData *)imageData];
    }
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  - (UIImage *) contactPicture:(NSInteger)contactId {
// Get contact from Address Book
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordID recordId = (ABRecordID)[contactId intValue];
ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, recordId);

// Check for contact picture
if (person != nil && ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {
    if ( &ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat != nil ) {
        // iOS >= 4.1
        return [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail)];
    } else {
        // iOS < 4.1
        return [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(person)];
    }
} else {
    return nil;
}
}
```

Comment: plz can you do it from the new contacts frame work in iOS 9 bcz address book is deprecated in iOS 9

Answer (score 0):

```
for (CNContact *contact in contacts) {
     if (!contacts) {
        contacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        if ( contact.imageData != nil ) {
           // iOS >= 4.1
           UIImage *CIMage = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)contact.imageData];
        }

     }

     NSString *string = [formatter stringFromContact:contact];
     NSLog(@"contact = %@", string);
     [contacts addObject:string];
  }



   //  Please this code is run in my app please try it.
```

Comment: thanks a lot can you also do it for the phone number with same framework