# Image of contacts is not fetching

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimage, cncontactstore

I am using this code to fetch contact image from device but its not printing any output.

```
if contact.isKeyAvailable(CNContactImageDataKey) {
    if let contactImageData = contact.thumbnailImageData {
        print("image \(String(describing: UIImage(data: contactImageData)))")
    } else {
        print("No image available")
    }
} else {
    print("No Key image available")
}
```

but it is printing only "No Key image available"  though some of my contacts have images . i tried imageData instead of thumbnailImageData but showing same results.

Comment: I saw this . this doesn't answer my question. :(

Comment: Did you add `CNContactImageDataAvailableKey` and `CNContactImageDataKey` on the keys to fetch?

Comment: getting same error after adding these.

Comment: I guess you haven't add permission in Info.plist... Add that, and then see if your problem get fixed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fetch contact image and phone Number in my app using Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34492804/how-to-fetch-contact-image-and-phone-number-in-my-app-using-objective-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure `CNContactImageDataAvailableKey` and `CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey` is contained in your `keysToFetch` and  remove the `isKeyAvailable` `if` clause:

```
if let imageData = contact.thumbnailImageData {
    print("image \(String(describing: UIImage(data: imageData)))")
} else {
    print("No image available")
}
```

Comment: i tried your code it shows "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CNPropertyNotFetchedException', reason: 'A property was not requested when contact was fetched.'"

Comment: Please show your fetch request. I assume you did not add `CNContactImageDataAvailableKey` and/or `CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey` to your `keysToFetch`. Updated answer.

Comment: i have add these two line now still  getting crash .
 let keysToFetch = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName), CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactImageDataAvailableKey ,CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey] as [Any]

Comment: i forgot to put CNContactImageDataKey. Thanks.

Comment: how to set ```String(describing: UIImage(data: imageData))``` to imageview?

Answer (score 1):

Add Keys to your fetch request (image keys missing)

```
 let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataAvailableKey, CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey]
 let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])
```