# How to fetch Contact Profile Picture in the relationships in SwiftUI?

Tags: image, swiftui, profile, cncontact

I have successfully fetched all contacts and now I want to add a new feature that goes beyond the capabilities of the Apple Contacts app. However, I have also successfully fetched the CNContactRelationsKey.

Here is the SwiftUI code:

```
ContactInfoTableView: View {
let contact: CNContact


var relationships: [CNLabeledValue<CNContactRelation>] {
    contact.contactRelations
}


var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        List {
            
            
            if !relationships.isEmpty {
                Section(header: Text("Relationships")) {
                    ForEach(relationships, id: \.self) { relation in
                        HStack {
                            if let label = relation.label {
                                let localizedLabel = CNLabeledValue<NSString>.localizedString(forLabel: label)
                                Text(localizedLabel)
                            }
                            
                            Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                                .padding(.leading)
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            
                            Text(relation.value.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

}

In the above code, it currently shows the Person SF Symbol Image for each contact. I need to fetch the profile picture from the relationships group, likely you can use the CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey to allow you can fetch the image data from the contact app, but how to display profile picture in the relationships group with the Image fetched data.

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: This wouldn’t have anything to do with SwiftUI

Comment: Yes, they are written in SwiftUI, but I need fetch profile picture in group.. I updated to show screenshot.

Comment: You would fetch it the same way, SwiftUI is for displaying/UI the fetching is not UI dependent. I’m just saying so you don’t limit your search to SwiftUI.

Comment: I am confused... SwiftUI is just design UI or display, not fetch? If that is true... Apple just wasted my time to learning swiftUI....I think I have to go back to stay UIKit development to make better than SwiftUI, I guess.

Comment: SwiftUI is basically a different UIKit they are both UI frameworks. Everything else is the same

Comment: SwiftUI is for rapid development of UI it is simpler and less versatile its underlying code is mostly UIKit. You can support all the platforms with one set of code. I suggest watching some of the WWDC 2019 videos such as “Meet SwiftUI”

Comment: Alright, I will go watch that WWDC19 video because I learning form Hacking With Swift, and other company has tutorials swiftUI as well. .

Comment: Yup should be very informative if you are proficient with UIKit. But SwiftUI Views are basically storyboard elements/UIViews with some UIViewController capabilities. “Demystify SwiftUI” is another good one too.

Comment: I heard lot of people say swiftUI is make more short code than UIKit like 1,000 lines to done like that... that is why I like swiftUI because of short code give me lot faster time than UIKit take long time to done.

Comment: It can minimize UI code not everything else such as fetching the image contacts, the code is the same the only difference is that in UIKit you would use the UIImage with a UIImageView and in SwiftUI you would use it with Image. Constraints, auto layout, etc are managed by SwiftUI. The “savings” are purely about UI.

Comment: I think there is no mistaken, it researched that there are limitations on fetching contact resources for developers in both UIKit and SwiftUI. These limitations are in place for various reasons. It's seem security by Apple to all Developers to accessing certain contact resources, such as the Profile Picture from the relationships group, may not be directly available through the provided APIs.

Comment: That is explained that Contact API has some are private resource. That's why I am not may fetch Profile picture in the group.

Comment: Search SO for the key you want there are a few different solutions some that say to use a different key that pulls the whole image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492220/image-of-contacts-is-not-fetching

Comment: I have that code that successfully fetches contact profile picture for all rest of contact list. However, I need to fetch the images from the contact group, as much relationship, link contact like that. it seems that the group does not have any available images.